# Non-cavitating ultrasound for denaturation of short strands of DNA (~20 bp)?

Tags: dna, dna-damage, ultrasound

I know that there is existing research on ultrasound-induced transient cavitation bubbles that mechanically denature DNA by generating violent shock waves locally in solution.

I would like to know if it is possible for **non-cavitating** ultrasound to denature short strands of DNA, ~20 base pairs in length (please cite sources, if possible). The mechanism should be mechanical, without involving thermal or cavitation effects of ultrasound. The ultrasound acts as a pressure wave, of the order of 10 MPa, and the DNA helices require a force of ~15 pN to initiate unzipping. I just need proof that this has been successfully demonstrated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does DNA denature?